# applying jquery modal mask

Tags: jquery

Is there a way to apply like a jquery mask on an image? my problem is i have an image that it's visibility is set to false. In the code behind, it does it's logic and if the value is set to something true, it sets the visibility of the image to true. What I want to accomplish is when the image is set to true, I want to apply like the jquery mask on the image so users cant interact with the form until they click the close link on the image. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you mean, you want to place a modal link on the webpage?

Comment: @Coding-Freak ... no, my image already have a link with it. ex: <asp:Image></asp:Image><asp:LinkButton></asp:LinkButton> ... I just need like a mask to cover the page when the image is up so users cant interact with the page until they close the image. Does this make sense?

Answer (score 1):

See here: http://www.queness.com/post/77/simple-jquery-modal-window-tutorial.  You can also go directly to their [demo](http://www.queness.com/resources/html/modal/jquery-modal-window.html) and try clicking on "Simple Window Modal"

The tutorial shows how to create a simple modal window.  It seems that this should work for you.

**Here is a [jsFiddle Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/vP2Gy/)**

Answer (score 0):

All jQuery does it cover the page behind your dialog with a div, so your clicks will never reach the elements under it, you can easily do something similar.